# Isolate light from a set of reflectors?

Tags: visible-light, reflection

How can I isolate light coming from a set of reflectors and eliminate ambient or diffuse light?

One idea I had was to use a polarizer.

Normally polarizers are used to reject reflected light, but if the polarizer is rotated so that it is at the exact angle of the reflected light, then it should maximize the relative level of the reflected light so that it will appear much brighter to the camera. I was thinking that I could enhance this effect even further by putting a polarizer on the light source. So the outgoing light is polarized, then a second polarizing filter on the camera is rotated until it captures the exact angle of light that is being reflected. This should eliminate nearly all the diffuse light.

The only problem is that in my scenario there are multiple reflectors. For example, imagine you have a tunnel and you have mounted multiple reflectors at various points on the wall of the tunnel. Will the setup above be able to capture all the reflectors at the same time because they are "more or less" the same angle, or will I only be able to capture the reflection from a single reflector at a time?

I guess the answer to this might depend on the *width* of the light source.

Comment: A classic solution to this problem is to modulate your source light, for example at 38 kHz, and then use a lock-in amplifier at your detector to only respond to light modulated at the correct frequency. Obviously this doesn't work if the ambient light is strong enough to saturate your detector.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it seems to be about engineering rather than physics. I'd also vote to close as "unclear what you're asking" because you've left out a lot of detail about what you're trying to do, what frequency light you're using, how fast the system has to respond, the power in the signals, etc. If you can clarify (by editing the question) how it's about experimental physics, and add enough detail for the question to be answerable, I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is to discriminate the background you want from the ambient light. The strategy you suggest is to polarise the light you want to detect, but your problem is that this is not a very good way of eliminating the background.

The usual way to do this is to use a modulated light source rather than a constant intensity. Suppose you modulate your light source at some frequency $f$, then the signal from your light detect or will consist of a signal of frequency $f$ superimposed on an approximately constant background from the ambient light. Simply use a filter that passes only signals with the frequency $f$ and that will eliminate the background.

The is probably outside the scope of the basic home experimenter, though simple frequency filters are not hard to make if you can use a soldering iron. However this approach is very widely used in experimental physics and it should be hard to find the equipment to do it.